# Calling a list of methods with next()

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I'd like to call a set of methods in succession -- the same way we use next() to go through an iterable.

The problem is that if I put them in a `iter()` they are all implicitly called at the same time, and `next()` does not work as it should.

What am I missing?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you add code which you have written?

Comment: It sounds like you are calling your methods and saving the results in a collection. Perhaps you should just be putting the method names in and perform a call later.

Comment: For example:
```f = iter([print("A"), print("B")])
next(f)```
The methods inside f are called at the same time and `next()` is by-passed and does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve? I've edited the original answer to show that it also allows you to pass args to these functions.

```
def append_num(x):
    x.append(4)
    
def append_other_num(x):
    x.append(5)


func_l = ['append_num', 'append_other_num']

l = [1, 2, 3]
print(l)

for x in func_l:
    eval(x + '(l)')
    print(l)

# Output:
# [1, 2, 3]
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as I thought, you are saving the results of calls into a `list`:

`f = iter([print("A"), print("B")])`

The `list` will contain two `None`s that are the result of calling `print()` (and btw `print("A")` is called first and `print("B")` second, so not at the same time, but before `f` is created)

What you can do instead is:

```py
funcs = iter([lambda:print("A"), lambda:print("B")])

f = next(funcs)
print('before call')
f()
print('after call')
```

Output:

```
before call
A
after call
```